# javascript "Cannot read property 'checked' of null"

Tags: javascript

```
function piliang() {
    var ids = "";
    var num = document.getElementsByName("check");
    for (var i = 0; 1 < num.length; i++) {
        if (num.item(i).checked) {
            ids = ids + num.item(i).value + ",";
        }
        alert(ids);
    }
```

run successfully

```
function piliang() {
    var ids = "";
    var num = document.getElementsByName("check");
    for (var i = 0; 1 < num.length; i++) {
        if (num.item(i).checked) {
            ids = ids + num.item(i).value + ",";
        }
    }
```

This gives out the following error:

> "Cannot read property 'checked' of null"

The first code also has this error, but it can run successfully

My English is not good, please try to explain it in code, thank you very much

Comment: Both codes look identical so that should not be the case.
Could you provide some more info. A good idea will be to print out the value using `console.log(num.item(i).checked)`

Comment: Thank you. That's settled @BabyGroot

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the `for` loop

```
function piliang() {
    var ids = "";
    var num = document.getElementsByName("check");
    for (var i = 0; 1 < num.length; i++) {    //use i instead of 1
        if (num.item(i).checked) {
            ids = ids + num.item(i).value + ",";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a pointer, this questions qualifies as a typographical mistake. There is a close option for such posts. So its a bad practice to answer such question. You can comment solution under question and if you have enough rep, then even post a close vote.